# How can I write a command that defines another macro which may optionally be prefixed by \global?

Tags: macros, grouping

In various contexts I define a macro such as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aedosomething{\ae@do@something}
\def\ae@do@something#1#2#3{%%
   %% do something with arguments #2 and #3
   \def#1{<result of doing something>}}
\makeatother
```

Here's a bit fuller (though pointless example)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aesavesumas{\ae@save@sum@as}
\def\ae@save@sum@as#1#2#3{%%
    \pgfmathparse{#2+#3}%%
    \edef#1{\pgfmathresult}}
\makeatother
```

In this particular instance, I am aware that there's a perfectly good macro

```
\pgfmathsetmacro
```

which is capable of computing and storing the information.  But my question isn't about the particulars of what's done with the extra arguments.  What I want to know is if I write something like

```
\global\aesavesumas\mysum{2}{3}
```

how to get the macro `\aesavesumas` to know that it should make the definition global so that, if `\aesavesumas\mysum{2}{3}` is called within a particular scope, the definition is saved for later use outside of that scope.

Comment: You can't; `\global` performs expansion until it finds something legal after it (`\def`, `\chardef`, `\advance` and so on; an assignment, to be precise), raising an error otherwise. Then the assignment is performed globally and `\global` disappears without leaving any trace: the information that the assignment was global cannot be accessed to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prefix `\global` can only go in front of an assignment. However, TeX expands tokens after `\global` in order to find the assignment. An example is the `\booltrue` macro in `etoolbox`:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\booltrue}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{if#1}
    {\etb@noglobal\etb@err@nobool{#1}}
    {\csname#1true\endcsname}}
```

If one does `\global\booltrue{foo}`, the latter macro is expanded leaving

```
\global\ifcsundef{iffoo}{...}{...}
```

and `\ifcsundef` is expanded; in case `\iffoo` is defined, TeX finds

```
\global\footrue
```

that needs another step of expansion for arriving to the final step

```
\global\let\iffoo\iftrue
```

that's the assignment TeX was looking for. In case `\iffoo` is not defined, TeX will have `\global\etb@noglobal` that becomes `\global\let\relax\relax` and it's an assignment that does nothing (except perhaps polluting the save stack, but it's unimportant, because an error message will be issued).

The problem is that the information whether the last assignment was global cannot be accessed to, nor can the information that the expansion was triggered by a lonesome `\global` hunting for a mate assignment.

Your assignment `\edef#1` comes in too late. Moreover `\pgfmathparse` begins with `\begingroup` and so you're doomed.

There's no problem instead if you use a postfix rather than a prefix. You can easily set up things so that `\global` is added when the call is

```
\aesavesumas*\mysum{2}{3}
```

and not when the `*` is missing.

Comment: This is more of an aesthetic question:  Would it be better to create a starred version of the command or to call `\aesavesumas\mysum{2}{3}` and then immediately `\xdef\mysum{\mysum}` or some other explicit global assignment?

Comment: @A.Ellett I'd avoid `\xdef\mysum{\mysum}` because of local-global assignment that's evil. However, the same effect is obtained with `\global\let\mysum\mysum` (since `\mysum` has already been defined with `\edef`).